# Why they keep on changing god?

Tags: gods, philosophy, belief

when i was a child they used to say me parents are god after that they used to say me teachers are god then they say me god is in everyone and now they are saying god is formless, why are you changing god? Why should I even believe anyone now who says me something about god , why doesnt god simply say this is the right path or this is god?How can I backup my belief?

Comment: Religious Texts show the correct path to Attain God, Follow them :-)

Comment: who are 'they'?

Comment: Did he not come and preach the right path years ago? Anyway to answer all the questions, god is everything, you cannot restrict him by saying he is only mother he is only father he is only formless he only has form etc. He is everything. He is Bhutabhavyabhavat prabhuh - the only thing that stays constant in the past future and present. No one can change god.

Comment: @Rambhakt for taking an example  guru Brahma Guru Vishnu but sometimes I see so many shrewd teachers in schools etc.

Comment: @Shashaank how can I be sure about the authenticity of religious texts how can I cross check them?

Comment: Most of the scriptures were composed by Ved Vyas, Veda Vyas is said to be the incarnation of Vishnu Himself, So there is no need to cross check them :-)

Comment: Regardless @AyushBora all those things you ask can be true at the same time. God is incomprehensible in many ways. Even without the authenticity, you can study Upanishads and understand how it must be this way, but it's not an easy path because of divine ineffability. Honestly, Bhagavad Gita explains in the easiest to understand way. Either way depends on how much depth you want to know. Having spent many years doing so I can tell you that understanding is nothing without doing. Sorry now, we have to close this question.